# Scrolling to dynamic element ID - React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement smooth scroll when user clicks on the `Next` or `Prev` button.

There will be many questions, With the below approach I've to define the `ref` manually.

Is there any way to optimise my code without declaring `Ref` for each component.

My Code

```
 const aRef = useRef(null);
  const bRef = useRef(null);
  const cRef = useRef(null);

  const scrollTo = (id: any) => {
    console.log(id);
    scrollToComponent(id);
  };

  const renderA = () => {
    return (
      <div ref={aRef} className="step" id="A">
        <h1>Component A</h1>
        <button className="next" onClick={() => scrollTo(bRef.current)}>
          NEXT
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const renderB = () => {
    return (
      <div ref={bRef} className="step" id="B">
        <h1>Component B</h1>
        <button className="next" onClick={() => scrollTo(cRef.current)}>
          NEXT
        </button>
        <button className="next" onClick={() => scrollTo(aRef.current)}>
          PREV
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {renderA()}
      {renderB()}
      {renderC()}
    </div>
  );
```

Working Stackblitz [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-3uh2cw?)

Answer (score 0):

[I've forked your project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hjhfqs?file=App.tsx) and with the correct functionality. In your sandbox, each of the components are using the same `"A"` id. They need unique id's.

Comment: Sorry its a typo issue, In smoth scroll is working only on certain scenario, So I want to use `react-scroll-to-component`

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on the scenarios that it does/doesn't work? I would advise against installing entire packages for the sole purpose of making something work that vanilla js can accomplish (for things as simple as smooth scrolling).

Comment: When I close the browser and start the app it works, after sometime when I NAVIGATE away from the app and comeback it dosen't work. I've no idea why this happening. I tested with diff browsers same results. 

In my other projects they've useed `react-scroll-to-component` hence I also wanted to implement the same using this component

Comment: I would need more information on your app structure to help, but this sounds like a more deeply rooted routing/navigation issue. I would advise you to look at your console logs when attempting to hit the button and it not working. Are you seeing errors?

Comment: No erros, When hit the button it just jumps to other screen without the scroll

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the issue in the forked stackblitz link I added? Try adding `html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }` to your stylesheet as well.